# Is com.google.android.gms:play-services-base needed?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Is the base library `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base` required for other Google Play Service libraries?

I cannot find any indication that it would be needed. Also the guide to [Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) only says:

> Google Actions, Base Client
>   Library   com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0

#### Side note:

An app is using these libraries, without base lib:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
```

The app reports some unreproducible crashes related to `com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite`, so I stumbled upon that base library.